# What are Site.com Shortcomings

Tags: site.com

I've looked into Site.com and it seems like it has a lot of potential, but it's not quite fully baked at this time.  I appreciate that Salesforce seems to be working hard on it and look forward to more from them.  I'm not trying to be antagonistic here...

Sometimes it is difficult to cut through all of the marketing with Salesforce (and other companies, to be fair) and I've learned that it is never safe to assume that some feature will work and/or be present in anything with Salesforce, no matter how basic, and with proprietary software like Site.com you get what you get.

I'd like to know what are the **full lists of deficiencies** that others have compiled while using or evaluating Site.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No support in sandboxes - This makes it especially difficult to create new sites that integrate with new large scale enterprise apps that require many new objects, fields, etc.
2. No support for SSL.
3. Lack of support for portal authentication integration (either customer or partner portal).
4. No merge capabilities - To be clear, this is just a CMS after all, so I'm not looking for svn, git, cvs full on capabilities. But something built in for moving individual files, comparing them, etc.  If two people are working on the same file the last one to save silently overwrites the other one.
5. Handling international sites is currently difficult with Site.com - for example, there's no way to create a 'master' page (or page element) and multiple child pages that represent the same content translated in another language. This makes it hard to keep track of changes you need to make in the international pages when you version/delete/move a page in the primary/initial language.
6. No way to limit contributors or publishers access to specific pages (e.g., only Anne from marketing should be able to modify the partner logo page).
7. Menu only supports links to pages w/in the site.
8. Bugs - Since Site.com is a relatively immature product, there are still some major bugs in it.
9. The CSS parser that is being used does not support some of the newer CSS3 features, such a media queries.

[Excellent post](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Site-com/Need-help-with-site-com-deficiencies/td-p/449047) in developer force boards.  It is great that the Site.com product team worked with this person.  I am very encouraged by stuff like that and have high hopes/expectations for Site.com. I've added in some of the issues not already on the list.  I just generalized all of the bugs into one because, in theory, they should get fixed.

Comment: I think this would be a good candidate for a Community Wiki article.

Comment: What do you mean by "no merge capabilites"?

Comment: @Benji - Existing Site.com site in production and multiple development projects in parallel, some of the pages and/or assets shared.  Thinking that with code in something like svn, I can branch, merge, rebaseline, etc.

Comment: @Benj - To be clear, this is just a CMS after all, so I'm not looking for svn, git, cvs full on capabilities.  But something built in for moving individual files, comparing them, etc.

Comment: @PeterKnolle got it, thanks.  I'd recommending updating your answer w/ these details because as I reader I had no idea what you meant!

Comment: I consolidated the answers into this one and changed it to community wiki as suggested by @MikeChale.

Answer (score 2):

Lack of support for portal authentication (either customer or partner portal) is a major limitation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Handling international sites is currently difficult with Site.com -- for example, there's no way to create a 'master' page (or page element) and multiple child pages that represent the same content translated in another language. This makes it hard to keep track of changes you need to make in the international pages when you version/delete/move a page in the primary/initial language.

And that's just one core piece of functionality, if you really want to get into web CMS translation workflow there are a bunch of other things you probably want automated -- check out slide 4 of this presentation for an example: http://www.slideshare.net/dmakam/building-global-sites-and-translation-workflow-with-a-wcm-perspective

Answer (score 1):

Price!

It's insanely expensive.

Thinking of what I can get at 1625$ /Month - It will be difficult to persuade me to check it.

Plus: the cloud/build/your/own/site/WYSIWYG is happening today with so many other startups and initiatives, that I don't think this will hold water for long.

Comment: Yup.  Compare it to http://www.stantive.com/OrchestraCMS_-_Overview#, for example.  I still feel like Site.com will end up as the top dog in the end because it seems like Salesforce is really pushing it and they have the competitive edge of being able to tap into non-public APIs, having their sales people push it, etc.